# How to fix getline() conflict while performing make in a release program?

Tags: ubuntu, makefile, getline

I'm new in computer science as a pharmacist trying to make computational biology. I trying to install some programas required to perform my experiments by using make command on Ubuntu 20.04.2 LTS. For the second time I receive a error about "conflicting types for 'getline'". After a search in the web, I notice a lot of comments about how to correct this while developing code, but none about a released program, so I have no idea how to fix this problem. Does anybody can help?

```
make
cc -O    -c -o addh.o addh.c
In file included from bbltyp.h:187,
                 from addh.c:27:
babel.h:56:14: error: conflicting types for ‘getline’
   56 | extern char *getline(FILE *fp);
      |              ^~~~~~~
In file included from bbltyp.h:20,
                 from addh.c:27:
/usr/include/stdio.h:616:18: note: previous declaration of ‘getline’ was here
  616 | extern __ssize_t getline (char **__restrict __lineptr,
      |                  ^~~~~~~
make: *** [<builtin>: addh.o] Error 1
```

http://www.ccl.net/cca/software/UNIX/babel/index.shtml

Thanks in advance,
Fernando

Comment: I followed the link. babel.h has no getline declaration.

Comment: So, where the error from?

Comment: That's what I'd like to know. `find / -name "babel.h"`